# Set multiple data on dataTransfer.setData

Tags: javascript, html, razor, razor-pages

It's possible to set multiple using dataTransfer?

**HTML**

```
<tr class="notfirst"
    draggable="true"
    ondragstart="drag(event, '@Model.getFormat(item)', '@Model.getColor(item)')"
    ondragover="allowDrop(event)"
>
```

**JS**

```
function drag(ev, format, color) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", format);
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", color); 
}
```

I can correctly pass `format` and `color` to my JS function but I cant add both to `dataTransfer` because `color` replaces `format`. I tried also to pass an object but didn't work either.

Answer (score 8):

You may push your data to a JSON object, then convert this object to a string with  JSON.stringify(). After that you will be able to pass the whole string to setData.

```
   let  obj = {prd_iId: 50 ,prd_sName: 'Ray Ban'};
   obj = {...obj, prd_sModel:'Aviator'};     
   e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", JSON.stringify(obj));
```

That will do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

> possible to set multiple using dataTransfer?

Yes.

If you don't want to serialize data you can simply set your data with different format arguments:

```js
  ev.dataTransfer.setData('formatText', format);
  ev.dataTransfer.setData('colorText', color);
```

get data like this

```js
  const format = ev.dataTransfer.getData('formatText');
  const color  = ev.dataTransfer.getData('colorText');
```

Comment: I tried to use setData() and  formated format value in camelcase, just like in your example, but then retrieving value, I found the format value in lowercase, strange

Comment: Strange. I updated the code, could you try it now? It might just be that you set it to a lowercase value. It shouldn't be lowercasing the string.